# Is the Youtube IFrame API Embedded Player broken on iPhone?

Tags: youtube-api

Recently I noticed that I am unable to click play on an embedded YT video in a web page on Iphone. I think they recently may have updated the API.

To verify, visit this link I found out in the wild, with an iphone:

[news article w/youtube embed](http://m.tucsonweekly.com/tucson/blogs/Post?basename=amys-baking-company-chooses-we-were-hacked-as-their-damage-control-response&day=14&id=TheRange&month=05&year=2013)

Tested on both Mobile Safari and Mobile Chrome.

The bug is that you cannot tap on the play button and have the video play. Interestingly enough, I tried this on an iPad and it worked fine.

Also of note, if you go grab the youtube-api example source code and try that it works... so that's where I'm getting stumped.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix/solve this?